# bash doesn't keep history

Tags: bash, history

I run Ubuntu 12.04, and for some reason bash does not keep my command history. the `~/.bash_history` file contains only 3 commands that I typed a few months ago.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**
here's the relevant content of my `.bashrc`:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
```

Comment: Check your bash history settings in `.bashrc`.

Comment: @jokerdino thx, I edited the question. It's the standard settings (I didn't touch them).

Comment: What is the output of "echo $SHELL"?

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 `/bin/bash`

Comment: What do you get from `echo $HISTFILE`?

Comment: what do you get for `$ history` and `# history`, only those 3 commands you typed earlier?

Comment: you should also check if `shopt` return `histappend on`

Comment: Another thing to try is to check the permissions of `~/.bash_history`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It could also be that root:root owns your .bash_history (*ROOT SHOULDN'T BE THE OWNER, YOUR USER SHOULD BE THE OWNER!*), in that case you need to:

```
$ chown user:user .bash_history
```

This apparently could happen magically when you do sudo bash a lot!

Comment: Wow, I completely gave up on this and forgot about it... +1 and accept.

Comment: Yeah this apparently happens when you do sudo bash a lot! :-)

Comment: Should user:user be replaced with the actual user name? Should both? Or just one?

Comment: hi  @Kvothe the first user from user:user is your username. $whoami (check)
the second user from user:user is your user group. when you do ls -als in a dir you will always see both user and group. For your personal user the group and user should be identical if not specified otherwise ...

Comment: Thanks. For me $whoami does not return anything. For the ls -als part you mean the two entries before the file size?

Comment: @Kvothe try just 'whoami' without the $ and to the second question, most probably yes. At least in my terminal those are: first owner and then group of the file.

Comment: my command above does following chown -> change owner to my username my user group on my local .bash_history ...

the $ sign is the symbol of local bash terminal, whereas # is the root terminal. Does not need to be included in the command, as in $whoami (means execute whoami on local terminal) #whoami (execute whoami on root terminal)

Comment: Ah thanks. (Usually I think people write `$ command`, i.e. with a space if they mean this.)

Comment: I don't know if there is a standard ... but I edited the orignal post anyway, and it looks better. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using gnome-terminal??, if so maybe check the permissions on .bash_history. It should be `-rw-r--r--`

To do so in a terminal `ls -la |grep .bash`, all 3 files should have the above permissions.
Otherwise try deleting .bash_history, restart & see if a history is then written

Note that the history is only written once the terminal is closed or quit.

Answer (score 1):

As commented above, this can be fixed with root->user ownership changes. Initial permissions may be from `-rw-r--r--` or any other variation and root ownership.

In my case I only had `.bash_history` owned by root but it is all of .bash_* that must be owned by user.

Comment: Welcome to ask ubuntu :) This is a 3 years old answered question and the solution you mentioned already exists in another answer .. just vote it up :)